# Using XTIFY to send rich text message through PHP

Tags: php, xtify

Do any one of you know how to send rich text xtify message using php. I am using xtify's GCM API and it works fine if I send a normal message. But How can I send a rich text message?

I am trying to get some information from http://developer.xtify.com/display/APIs/Push+API+2.0 but there is not much help for sending a rich text or may be I am ignoring the most obivious things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the JSON packet I need to pass a rich object with message and subject like the example given in the link.